# How can you alter the margins in Nimbus Look and Feel

Tags: java, swing, nimbus

I'm trying to use Nimbus Look and Feel and I can't simply plug it in to replace other Look and feel because it adds some external padding around each component.

So, I would like to remove this padding. This is the [list](http://jasperpotts.com/blogfiles/nimbusdefaults/nimbus.html) of defaults that can be changed, however the following code changes nothing.

```
UIManager.put("Button.contentMargins", new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

Other values are working as expected.

How can I remove this padding?

**EDIT**

I believe content margins is referring to the internal padding.

**EDIT**

Looking at the [source code](http://kickjava.com/src/com/sun/java/swing/plaf/nimbus/ButtonPainter.java.htm) the external padding seems to be hard-coded. I believe it's added to allow for the focus selection property.

Should this be considered a bug? No other L&F does this, and with this extra padding it's not possible to reuse the same layout (as previous layouts all will be assuming no padding).

Answer (score 4):

I found that you have to set those defaults right after you set the look and feel (i.e., before you start creating any UI components):

```
try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
    UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Table.cellNoFocusBorder", new Insets(0,0,0,0));
    UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Table.focusCellHighlightBorder", new Insets(0,0,0,0));
    Insets buttonInsets = new Insets(3, 6, 3, 6);
    UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Button.contentMargins", buttonInsets);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Also note that you need to set them on the "LookAndFeelDefaults" not the "developer" defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Force nimbus to create the defaults first by calling getDefaults():

```
NimbusLookAndFeel laf = new NimbusLookAndFeel();
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf);
UIDefaults def = laf.getDefaults();
def.put("Button.contentMargins", new Insets(0,0,0,0));
def.put("DesktopIcon.contentMargins", new Insets(0,0,0,0));
def.put("Label.contentMargins", new Insets(0,0,0,0));
```

UIManager.put() won't store the settings in the nimbus defaults if the defaults was not initialized first.