# JTabbedPane tab height with nimbus

Tags: java, swing, tabs, jtabbedpane, nimbus

I would like the change the height tab's tabbedpane, and to do so I tried several method without any success.  First I tried with a spacer icon, the height is good, but the text of the tab is not center anymore.  Then I tried to change Nimbus L&F properties, TabbedPane.tabInsets, TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab.contentMargins, and TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTabArea.contentMargins nothing change.  Finally I tried to extend BasicTabbedPaneUI and overide calculateTabHeight, but the background of the tab is not painted anymore.

Comment: Please post questions from a single account [wotan2009](http://stackoverflow.com/users/671899/wotan2009).

Comment: see [Java Swing: How can you alter the margins in Nimbus Look and Feel](http://stackoverflow.com/q/718977/307767)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `setTabComponentAt` to set a custom component on the tab. You can set any component you want. If you just want a label with a bigger height, give `setComponentAt` a JLabel with a border, or with its preferredSize set.

Comment: I just tried, it changes the tab content, but it is not for setting the tab title.

Comment: then you neither set a border nor the preferredSize.